# Android Pdf Viewer Library : PDF is not loading using URL

Tags: android, kotlin, androidpdfviewer

Using URL, I am trying to load pdf through AndroidViewLibrary.
But throwing error

"java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"

Below is my code.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.act_pdf_view)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

val uri = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"

mBinding.pdfView.fromUri(Uri.parse(uri))
.enableSwipe(true)
.swipeHorizontal(false)
.enableAnnotationRendering(true)
.scrollHandle(DefaultScrollHandle(this))
.load()
}
```

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/72

There are lots of libraries to load pdf file.

Comment: If you find the solutions for the same. please share your library name and link so I can help you.